# LSTM model Evaluation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have the following LSTM model, its input is embedded by the word2vec model:

[LSTM Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8y4M.jpg)

I need your opinion about the model evaluation as shown in the below pictures [Accuracy vs epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7Wlv.jpg) [Losses vs. epochs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXtFd.jpg)
How to improve the losses vs. epochs curve?

Comment: This question is a bit too general. Maybe rethink it and ask a more specific question. One could take multiple lectures on this topic ;)

Comment: @Rafael-WO What I mean by my question is, Is my Losses vs epochs curve accepted as a good model?

Comment: what's the different between the blue line and yellow line?

Comment: Blue line is the training losses, and the yellow one is the evaluation losses

Answer (score 0):

Training your LSTM model.
Training is a processing of update your model's parameter by epoch, the accuracy will promote and loss will decline by epoch.

Comment: Do you mean increasing the number of epochs?